# Split string using IFS

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have written a sample script to split the string but it is not working as expected

```bash
#!/bin/bash
IN="One-XX-X-17.0.0"
IFS='-' read -r -a ADDR <<< "$IN"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    echo "Element:$i"
done
#split 17.0.0 into NUM
IFS='.' read -a array <<<${ADDR[3]};
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "Num:$element"
done
```

- Actual output

  ```
  One
  XX
  X
  17.0.0
  17 0 0
  ```
- but I expected the output to be:

  ```
  One
  XX
  X
  17.0.0
  17
  0
  0
  ```

Comment: By the way, if one of the answers below solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix, (see also [S. Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397208/165517) for background), with sensible output:

```
#!/bin/bash
IN="One-XX-X-17.0.0"
IFS='-' read -r -a ADDR <<< "$IN"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    if [ "$i" = "${i//.}" ] ; then 
        echo "Element:$i" 
        continue
    fi
    # split 17.0.0 into NUM
    IFS='.' read -a array <<< "$i"
    for element in "${array[@]}" ; do
        echo "Num:$element"
    done
done
```

Output:

```
Element:One
Element:XX
Element:X
Num:17
Num:0
Num:0
```

---

Notes:

- It's better to put the conditional *2nd* loop *in* the *1st* loop.
- `bash` pattern substitution (`"${i//.}"`) checks if there's a `.` in an element.  (A `case` statement might be simpler, albeit less similar to the *OP*'s code.)
- `read`ing `$array` by inputting `<<< "${ADDR[3]}"` is less general than `<<< "$i"`.  It avoids needing to know *which* element has the `.`s.
- The code assumes that printing "*Element:17.0.0*" is unintentional. 
  If That behavior *is* intended, replace the main loop with:

  ```
  for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
     echo "Element:$i" 
     if [ "$i" != "${i//.}" ] ; then 
     # split 17.0.0 into NUM
         IFS='.' read -a array <<< "$i"
         for element in "${array[@]}" ; do
             echo "Num:$element"
         done
     fi
  done
  ```

Comment: `case $i in (*.*) ...` would be a more canonical way to check that `$i` contains `.` (and also portable to `sh`). If you're into kshisms, see also: `[[ $i = *.* ]]`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Already mentioned `case` in *notes* at end, but we agree.  (Since the OP uses both `<<<` and *arrays*, this isn't much of a `sh` question.)

Answer (score 12):

In old versions of `bash` you had to quote variables after `<<<`. That was fixed in 4.4. In older versions, the variable would be split on IFS and the resulting words joined on space before being stored in the temporary file that makes up that `<<<` redirection.

In 4.2 and before, when redirecting builtins like `read` or `command`, that splitting would even take the IFS for that builtin (4.3 fixed that):

```
$ bash-4.2 -c 'a=a.b.c.d; IFS=. read x <<< $a; echo  "$x"'
a b c d
$ bash-4.2 -c 'a=a.b.c.d; IFS=. cat <<< $a'
a.b.c.d
$ bash-4.2 -c 'a=a.b.c.d; IFS=. command cat <<< $a'
a b c d
```

That one fixed in 4.3:

```
$ bash-4.3 -c 'a=a.b.c.d; IFS=. read x <<< $a; echo  "$x"'
a.b.c.d
```

But `$a` is still subject to word splitting there:

```
$ bash-4.3 -c 'a=a.b.c.d; IFS=.; read x <<< $a; echo  "$x"'
a b c d
```

In 4.4:

```
$ bash-4.4 -c 'a=a.b.c.d; IFS=.; read x <<< $a; echo  "$x"'
a.b.c.d
```

For portability to older versions, quote your variable (or use `zsh` where that `<<<` comes from in the first place and that doesn't have that issue)

```
$ bash-any-version -c 'a=a.b.c.d; IFS=.; read x <<< "$a"; echo "$x"'
a.b.c.d
```

Note that that approach to split a string only works for strings that don't contain newline characters. Also note that `a..b.c.` would be split into `"a"`, `""`, `"b"`, `"c"` (no empty last element).

To split arbitrary strings you can use the split+glob operator instead (which would make it standard and avoid storing the content of a variable in a temp file as `<<<` does):

```
var='a.new
line..b.c.'
set -o noglob # disable glob
IFS=.
set -- $var'' # split+glob
for i do
  printf 'item: <%s>\n' "$i"
done
```

or:

```
array=($var'') # in shells with array support
```

The `''` is to preserve a trailing empty  element if any. That would also split  an empty `$var` into one empty element.

Or use a shell with a proper splitting operator:

- `zsh`:

  ```
  array=(${(s:.:)var} # removes empty elements
  array=("${(@s:.:)var}") # preserves empty elements
  ```
- `rc`:

  ```
  array = ``(.){printf %s $var} # removes empty elements
  ```
- `fish`

  ```
  set array (string split . -- $var) # not for multiline $var
  ```

Answer (score 1):

With **awk** it would cost you one line:

```
IN="One-XX-X-17.0.0"

awk -F'[-.]' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s : %s\n",($i~/^[0-9]+$/?"Num":"Element"),$i }' <<<"$IN"
```

- `-F'[-.]'` - field separator based on multiple characters, in our case `-` and `.`

---

The output:

```
Element : One
Element : XX
Element : X
Num : 17
Num : 0
Num : 0
```

Comment: The same could be done with `IFS=-. read -r a array <<< "$IN"`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, it's different. You are showing just step with converting a string into array. But my one-line is dedicated to cover all: splitting into fields, processing and outputting. I'm not compete with your answer, they are just different

Answer (score 1):

Often it is possible to put the string splitting into a subshell. If so, that solves the trouble of properly restoring noglob or IFS settings.

```
a="world-thing-hello"
t="$(set -o noglob; IFS=-; set -- $a; echo $2)"
echo "This is the $t."
```

This is the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here my way:

```
OIFS=$IFS
IFS='-'
IN="One-XX-X-17.0.0"
ADDR=($IN)
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
 echo "Element:$i"
done
IFS='.'
array=(${ADDR[3]})
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
  echo "Num:$element"
done
```

result as expected:

```
Num:17
Num:0
Num:0
```

Comment: That `$IN` is invoking the split+glob operator. Here, you don't  want the glob part (try on `IN=*-*-/*-17.0.0` for instance), so you'd want to do `set -o noglob` before invoking it. See my answer for details.

Comment: In general, try to avoid "saving" `IFS` and setting it globally. You really only want to change the value of `IFS` for when `$IN` is expanded, and you also don't want pathname expansion performed on the expansion. Further, `OIFS=$IFS` doesn't distinguish between the cases when `IFS` was set to an empty string, and when `IFS` was completely unset.