# How to feed pipe-separated content of a shell variable as input to an array variable

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a issue in processing data of below variable to the dynamic array

```
variable_1='A|B|C|D' -> dynamic_array=(A B C D)
```

I tried using sed command to replace '|' with space and how do I pass data to dynamic_array

Is their any way to achieve within one line of code?

Comment: What is the shell?

Comment: Some good reading -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397205/split-string-using-ifs

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Without changing `IFS`, [since Bash 4.4](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/CHANGES#L1733):

```
readarray -td '|' arr < <(printf '%s' "$var")
```

```
$ var='A|B|C|D'
$ readarray -td '|' arr < <(printf '%s' "$var")
$ echo "${arr[0]}"; echo "${arr[3]}"
A
D
```

See [`help readarray`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) for explanation.

Note: My previous suggestion (`readarray -td '|' arr <<< "$var"`), although briefer, would insert a spurious newline at the last array element, as Freddy pointed.

Comment: Note that it turns both `var='A|B'` and `var='A|B|'` into `arr=(A B)`, though it turns `var=''` into `arr=()` and `var='|'` into `arr=('')`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `bash`:

---

You can make use of word splitting. Internal Field Separator (IFS) defaults to space, tab or newline. But you can override it with setting the `IFS` environment variable, then you can use the normal ways to create a variable:

```bsh
set -f # disable filename expansion
IFS='|' arr=($variable_1)
```

or `declare`:

```
IFS='|' declare -a 'arr=($variable_1)'
```

or `read`:

```
IFS='|' read -ra arr  <<<  "$variable_1"
```

---

If you change the `IFS` variable like this, you may want to save it first in another variable and reset it afterwards:

```bsh
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
# my commands
IFS="$OLD_IFS"
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit

Comment: You should mention that after the first, `IFS` will stay set to `|`, potentially breaking other commands. `IFS='|' arr=($var)` does NOT work like `IFS= read ..` -- IFS does not revert to its old value after that.

Comment: `read -ra` is the best answer, but I would strongly encourage you to be more vigilant about [quoting your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells). The first one in particular is not recommended unless you also do `set -f`

Comment: thanks, updated my answer to reflect your comments. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @glennjackman, `read -ra` only works for data that doesn't contain newline characters. It also removes trailing empty elements. For that you need: `set -o noglob; IFS='|'; array=($string"")`

Comment: @plumo note that when you do `var=value command` then the var is _only set for the duration of the command_. I'd pull out a reference from the manual but I'm on my phone

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `zsh`, you can use the `s` parameter expansion flag which will work whatever characters or non-characters the elements contain:

```
$ string=$'first element|second\nbinary\x80element\0||second-last|'
$ array=("${(@s[|])string}")
$ typeset -p string array
typeset string=$'first element|second\nbinary\M-\C-@element\C-@||second-last|'
typeset -a array=( 'first element' $'second\nbinary\M-\C-@element\C-@' '' second-last '' )
```

Note that the empty string is split into one empty element (`string=''` gives `array=( '' )`, not `array=( )`).